# What is the best way to communicate to a user that a pricing package is no longer available?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, user-centered-design

We currently offer 4 pricing packages, but will no longer be offering one of them.

What is the best way to communicate this to users, particularly the ones who were on that (deprecated) plan and are interested in purchasing this deprecated plan for their other accounts (note that users can have multiple accounts with a plan associated to each)?

What is the best way to communicate this before they reach support, presumably to complain about the "missing" plan?

Within the product, we also display the pricing table for them to easily manage their existing plan or upgrade to another plan. In this pricing table we display *all* of the plans highlighting:

- The plan they are on
- The plan we recommend/most popular plan

If they are currently on the deprecated plan, do you recommend we still display this column, but grayed out?

Comment: Hi Liv Beng, I have the feeling that this is more a marketing question than UX since the only two possibilities are no price column or grayed out. I imagine a telephone company leaving an old price plan as inactive in the internet all the problems it may have with the users.

Comment: @SolarMike - No, the plan isn't getting eliminated because of "an increase in demand." It is being eliminated because it was hurting our revenue more than it was helping. No need to be rude.

Answer (score 1):

From a marketing perspective, I wouldn't even mention the deprecated plan -- it'll just show customers that you've hiked up prices, and make them unhappy before they even purchase (or they might take it as a sign to haggle and call in to request the lower price).

What percentage of your customer base will be asking about this? You might be able to wait it out if it's not a lot of people. But if you're getting enough calls about this, I'd just have a tiny piece of copy at the bottom addressing it:

"Is your current plan not listed here? We've recently restructured our pricing plans. You can keep your current plan, but all new accounts use one of these plans."
(this addresses their concern respectfully but firmly)